# Fuzzy, Phonetic and Wildcard Search

Tags: search, fast-for-sharepoint, dynamics-crm

We've got Dynamics AX setup but are having some issues with the search that I am hoping to clarify. When using the SharePoint search to find clients it is not satisfying our Use Cases. The search is going through the BCS.

From my findings I believe that only prefix wildcards are supported and phonetics is only available with People (Nicknames)

These are our use cases

i.e if we have a Customer called 'Contoso' all of these should return the result

- Conto* - Currently works
- *ontoso - No Results
- *onto* - No Results
- Cintoso - No Results

We also have scenarios where a company could be Foo **Ltd** or Bar **Limited**, a search for Ltd should find both as it's a synonym. I believe the Thesaurus could help here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361734(v=office.14).aspx

My question is, would FAST support these results?

Comment: Fast will not be better for your WildCard searches. It handles wildcards the same way. for "Cintoso" you would have to add it as a synonym

Comment: Is there any option I have to enable to wildcard searching? It seems very limited.

Comment: It is very limited, since it is only prefix. I'm no expert on FAST, but since FAST is incorporated in SP 2013 and no other forms of Wild search works there, I do think prefix is the only working wildcard search also in FAST

Comment: It looks like FQL does support it - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394462(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: True, but not with your syntax? :)